# how to create standard ERC721 token

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js

how to create **ERC721 token** standard contract? I am unable to import openzepplin libraries of erc721 standard. if someone could help me to give the link of the repository or how to import openzepplin libraries in Remix?

Comment: just download the files at Github, compile, and send the transaction   to `nil` address

Comment: github link please

Comment: its the third row in SERP of Google

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all i would suggest you to use VS code or whatever IDE on your machine and make sure you installed ipfs using command

```
npm i -g ipfs
```

for react project tho and make sure to run (from root project)

```
npm install
```

to actually put the library (ipfs) into your node_modules

Then hopefully you'll be able to import openzepplin libraries of ERC721
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrFmq.png)